# Understand ES6 Shorthand

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to understand a js shortand which came up to me studying React.
This is it: `{this.state.isModalOpen && <div className="modal onClose={this.handleClose}">` I simplified for the sake of understanding.

In the state object I have isModalOpen set to true and handleClose is a method which toggle the isModalOpen to true or false when triggered. I understand what it does but I don't understand but what would be a more declarative way to write it to understand where it comes from?

I can write the whole class if needed, but I think it is a pretty newbie question.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it the `&&` you don't understand?

Comment: Note that nothing in the code you've quoted is "ES6"-specific. `&&` is JavaScript and has behaved the same way since ~1996 (JavaScript was created in '95, but in that initial version, `&&` and `||` resulted in booleans; the current more-useful behavior was added within a year or two I believe). The `<div ...>` is [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html), which isn't part of JavaScript at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, what I don't understand is why if the variable is set to true the div should be returned, I don't understand the syntax, is it the corrispective of "if it's true then return"? I have never seen such use of && operator. Thanks